# Why does Minnesota Fats require Bert Gordon?

Tags: the-hustler

Gordon stakes people for a very big chunk, depending upon the player, of their winnings. But Fats is a famous player who firstly does not need someone to arrange games and secondly has his own money.

At the end of the first match with Eddie, Fats hands Gordon a big wad of bills (note that some of the bills in those days could have been bigger than 100s, 500 dollar bills were common) so it is clear that Gordon was not just a spectator.

I could see it being possible that a permanent arrangement could have been established, perhaps years before, between Fats and Bert Gordon. It is also clear that Gordon is a criminal of some sort, able to believably threaten Eddie with violence later when he fails to give Gordon his cut of his winnings from the second match -- this may be why Fats never tells Gordon that he no longer needs his backing. Also, with such large quantities involved, maybe being under Gordon's protection assures both that Fats will be paid by his opponents and no one will roll him (or extort Fats, offering their own "protection").

I have not read the book in a long time but I do not recall the relationship between Gordon and Fats being discussed much.

Answer (score 3):

Gordon is a coach, a cooler. He watches, analyzes, decides how much and when to play big money. He looks (through) people. He's a councel, knowing when players are weak, vulnerable.

> **Bert Gordon** : I don't think there's a pool player alive shoots better pool than I saw you shoot the other night at Ames. You got talent.
>
> **Fast Eddie** : so I got talent. So what beat me?
>
> **Bert Gordon** : character.

He's the one not feeling the stress or strain of the long hours playing, he takes facts and decides what to do. That's why he says: "now you can play him" or "stop, we've lost enough money and won't make it back".

But he's also an impresario (on the verge of being a mob too, threatening Fast Eddie), taking his percentage from the player he coaches. Thus, the bills.

> **Fast Eddie** : what if I don't pay ya, Bert?
>
> **Bert Gordon** : you don't pay me? You're gonna get your thumbs broken again. And your fingers. If I want 'em to, they're gonna break your right arm in three or four places.
>
> **Minnesota Fats** : you better pay him, Eddie.
>
> **Fast Eddie** : so you figure you're still my manager, huh?
>
> **Bert Gordon** : I'm a business-man, kid.

From [Silver Screen Classics](https://silverscreenclassicsblog.wordpress.com/2019/05/24/bert-gordon-arch-villain-the-performance-of-george-c-scott-in-the-hustler-1961/), Bert Gordon is the archetype of the villain, and one of a kind!

> Yet perhaps the most dangerous villain of all is the one that is not so visible – at least initially. Bert Gordon is the man who wants to own and exploit him (Fast Eddie).
>
> Bert Gordon is professional gambler<sup>1</sup>, who knows the odds and plays to win, leaves the card game to watch Eddie play the legendary Minnesota Fats, whom Bert *owns* and bankrolls.

From [wicked problems: The Hustler](http://tamingwickedproblems.com/wicked-problems-at-the-movies-the-hustler/)

> Bert Gordon is a shrewd, amoral, big-time gambler and a fixture in the pool hall, constantly on the lookout for talented players to back. He acts as Fats' manager, arranging for matches and managing the money. His overriding  interest is making as much money as possible and he is ready to destroy anyone who stands in his way.
>
> Bert Gordon is also ambitious, but what he wants is both simpler and more complex than Eddie: He wants money and control to run the show.  "*I'm already rich*" he tells Eddie. "*I like the action. That's one thing I think you're good for – action.*"

If I had to rank/categorize Bert Gordon, he would be a mentor, with [manager's skills](https://www.risely.me/the-complete-guide-to-analytical-skills-for-managers/) like

1. Analytical Skills
2. Guidance Ability
3. Emotional Competence

He would also be an asset and major advantage in a player's game because of what Linda Phillips-Jones, Ph.D. describes in her [Mentoring Skills Model](https://my.lerner.udel.edu/wp-content/uploads/Skills_for_Sucessful_Mentoring.pdf)<sup>3</sup>:

1. Building trust
2. Identifying goals and current reality
3. Providing corrective feedback
4. Managing risks
5. Opening doors

**Why does Minnesota Fats require Bert Gordon?** : these are my 2 cents, but it would be because he has a coach/mentor he can trust, leaving him able to focus on the game only<sup>4</sup>. Bert chooses the opponents, backs him up with money, analyzes the game, and provides feedback. One takes care of the human moves, the other of the felt moves.

---

<sup>1. first seen in a card game, drinking milk to stay focus on the game and the players.</sup>

<sup>2. quotes from the movie with emphasis on names are from [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054997/characters/nm0001715)</sup>

<sup>3. "Fast" Eddie Felson is doing just that with Vincent Lauria in [The Color of Money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Color_of_Money)</sup>

<sup>4. "*He gives the impression of a man purified by pool, who has moved through all the sad compromises and crooked bets and hustling moves and emerged as a man who simply, elegantly, plays the game. He has long ago given up hustling; unlike Eddie, he makes his living by dependably being the best, time after time, so that others can test themselves against him.*" (from [Great Movies Reviews](https://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/great-movie-the-hustler-1961))</sup>

Comment: Yes, it is in fact Gordon who tells the very badly losing (initially) Fats to stick with Eddie because "he's a loser." But I question whether the experienced Fats needs Bert to tell him this. The book explains that while Eddie pays no attention to his personal appearance during the long match, Fats washes his face and cleans his fingernails. I have seen (in a poker game) people stay up all night and lose after being ahead a lot -- this was a very realistic aspect of the movie. It's painful to watch someone go from 11k ahead to zero, especially because in 1960 11k was easily 100k today.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how Gordon came to own Fats. Seems, as mentioned, that he would no longer need him but perhaps in his past he was in a desperate situation that Gordon got him out of in, but it was like, Now, if I do this, the relationship is forever. Maybe he had the same weakness that Eddie had when he was younger.

Comment: @releseabe : I've added some data, and developed some points I found interesting, hopefully going your way and answering your additional questions.